# MySQL Innodb - Truncate Partition. Does it reclaims space?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Once a month I need to remove all the old data from the table. Previously I was copying all the needed data to another table, then drop the original table and rename the new table as original. When I ran drop table the space is reclaimed.

But now I am deciding to use Partitioning in the table. So my question is when I will do:

`ALTER TABLE mytable TRUNCATE PARTITION partition`

Will it reclaims the space? If it does not reclaims the space then am I left with only choice to OPTIMIZE the table or is there anything else I am missing? Since doing OPTIMIZE PARTITION on innodb table will lock the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not said what value `innodb_file_per_table` was set to when you created the table.  If `OFF`, you have no chance of shrinking any file on disk.  Instead, you can only send it off to be 'free' and potentially reused by inserts.  With `ON`...

A third option is `ALTER TABLE REORGANIZE PARTITION ...` where you essentially state the same partition as the 'from' and 'to'.  This degenerate version effectively does what `OPTIMIZE PARTITION` should do (but fails to).

Fourth option, which would work in *some* partition types:  `DROP PARTITION` and add it back.

Yes, `OPTIMIZE PARTITION` rebuilds the entire table.  After 5.6.17 (5.7.4), you *may* may be able to do it non-blocking (`ALGORITHM=INPLACE`).

Even if `TRUNCATE` does not free the space, will you be adding data back in?  Of so, then one could argue that it is "not a problem".

Comment: Yes innodb_file_per_table is on that's why when I drop the table it gives me the space back. Does REORGANIZE partition blocks the table? or maybe it is so fast that it does not matter?

Comment: I suspects it blocks the table long enough to copy over the partition(s) involved.  In your case (after truncation), that should be fast.

Comment: Just for your knowledge. I just tested on AWS RDS with 100gb of table divided in 4 partitions. Other 8 were already empty. When I truncate each partition the space was immediately available without doing OPTIMIZE, REORGANIZE. Is this normal?

Comment: Maybe.  `TRUNCATE` may be implemented as `DROP` + `CREATE`.  The manual may say specifically.